# Php: Function to replace all chars except valid RFC 3986

Tags: php

Looking for a simple validation script that will replace all chars in a string except RFC 3986 valid chars

A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, ., _, ~, :, /, ?, #, [, ], @, !, $, &, ', (, ), *, +, ,, ; and =. Also any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding (%hh)

Comment: What have you tried so far? A regular expression with character c lasses would remove those for you with preg_replace(). Then you can use `rawurlencode()` to do the 3986 encoding.

Answer (score 4):

[rawurlencode()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)